# Sharepoint newform populate field with selected lookup info

Tags: workflow, javascript, spservices

I have used SPServices cascading drop-down list successfully in a SharePoint list form. But what I would also like to achieve is when a item is selected form a dropdownlist (lookup item), an other field is dynamically populated with related data.

i.e. When I have an order line and select a product from the list, the price of the product is populated in the price box.

I know something simular can be done with a workflow, but I prefer javascript since it is less heavy en much faster.

Thanks in advance,

Bas

Answer (score 2):

Create your product list as you want, just add price column as number to it as well.

In Order List, create the desired columns, for price/quantity create a number column and for Sub-total create a calculate column with formula =[Price_Col_Name]*[Qty_Col_Name].

Now open the Order List new form. Now click on setting(gear) icon on top right corner and select edit page. Now follow steps:

1. Click on link `Add a Web Part`.
2. In Categories column select `Media and Content` and in Part column select `Script editor` and click on `Add` button.
3. You'll see that the web part is added to your page. And inside web part there will be a hyperlink saying `Edit Snippet`. Click on edit snippet.
4. A new popup will be open with a text area to write script. In this copy page the following script (make sure you change the variable where ever i mentioned, dont worry, I'll tell how you can find those as well).

**Script**

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    var OrgPriceId = "input[title='OrgPrice']";
    var ProductDropDownId = "select[title='Product']";
    var siteUrl = "http://site_url/";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(OrgPriceId).prop("readonly", "readonly");
        $(ProductDropDownId).on('change', LoadPrice);
    });

    function LoadPrice(){
        var productId = $(ProductDropDownId).val();
        if(productId != null && productId != ""){
            var url = siteUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Product')/items(" + productId + ")";
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json,odata=verbose",
                },
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.d !== undefined){
                        $(OrgPriceId).val(data.d.Price); // data.d will remain same you need to find Price column name.
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

</script>
```

In this script you need to edit following things:
1. `"input[title='OrgPrice']"` to `"input[title='Org Price Column Name']"`.
2. `select[title='Product']` to `select[title='Product column name']`.
3. `http://site_url/` to your exact site URL. If you are unsure what is your site collection URL then open any of the list Product or Order and remove everything from `List/Order........`. Take the first part.
4. And finally `data.d.Price` to the `data.d.Price_Column_Internal_Name`. If you dont know how to get this. Open Product List Setting, under columns section find Price Column and click on it, it will navigate to a new page. In the Url find `&Field=Internal_Name`. Grab the internal name and replace it.

Repeat the same steps for Edit form as well.

Comment: It's not working yet. The Org Price Colmn Name and Product Colmn name are those the name of the columns of the original parent list?

Comment: No it will be the name of Order list. Since we are dealing with Order List here.

Comment: Well, I have tried getting it working this weekend, but without success. Here I have some screenshots with additional info and the original column names (in dutch) [img1](http://imgur.com/5hMVndH) [img2](http://imgur.com/tvdrUTT) [img3](http://imgur.com/lU5aeWI) [img4](http://imgur.com/0mduyyu)

Comment: Start with adding JQuery to page and put statement like `$("input[title='Org Price Column Name']")`. And see the output. If the output contains `length = 1` then you are on right track.

Comment: Make sure you do this on Order New Form.

Comment: I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Where should I get the output? In console? or in Browser display? Still not sure what you mean with Org Price Column Name. Could you by any chance refer to the screenshot's I have attached earlier?

Comment: Yes, I mean to check on browser console. Also by `Org Price Column Name` i mean the name of your `Price` column in Order List. To get this, just open `New Form` and right click on Price column input box and select `inspect element` and copy the entire title text and replace `Org Price Column Name` with copied text. and run the command on browser console. Make sure your has reference to JQuery.

Comment: did you made any progress?

Comment: No, I just can't seem to get it working.

Comment: are you able to add JQuery to page?

Comment: When I look in the browser console I can see jQuery loaded. But that's ad far as I get.

Comment: Added via a Script/Content editor web part on Quantity List New Form? If yes, then right click on Price Column and click on `Inspect Element`. It will open developer console and give you some reference to `<input type="text" ......`. In this find the HTML attribute title and copy they text next to it i.e. it looks like this, `title="my example title"` and you need to take out `my example title` and on browser console run the command `$("input[title='my example title']").length`. If this gives 1 as an output you are good to go. If not, identify the right html control.

Comment: Ok did that for the field where I would like the price to be copied to, and that works. Note that the field with the price associated with the Product lookup column is not on the new and edit form.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this, but following two will be what I prefer.

**Lookup Columns - Additional Fields**
Based on the lookup column, you can get additional columns. So you just need to select the lookup column and the additional columns will get value automatically when you save/update you list item (which have lookup column). Good for situations when you are using OOTB new forms. When you add lookup column it gives you option to all the related columns, see in image below.

[image]

**REST API**
If you are doing custom forms and dont want additional lookup columns, then just use SP REST API to get the details you require. In this you need to make an ajax call to the REST API list item endpoint and you'll get all the data. You need to get the lookup item ID (which can be extracted from dropdown, see in image below). And finally make the ajax call to Item EndPoint. The URL will be `http://url_to_site_collection/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Title_of_List')/Items(extracted_item_id)`. This will return a JSON object which you can use. Or to read on [REST API follow the URL](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints).

[image]

Following is the jQuery ajax call to get the item result.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://server:port/sites/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('name_of_list')/items(item_id_must_be_number)",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json,odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function(productData){
            console.log(productData); // This JSON object will give you price.
        }
    });
```

Comment: The first option is not sufficient for my needs, since I need to fetch a product price to use in a calculated field (Sub-total). The second one might work only I'm not an experienced programmer so an example would be highly appreciated.

Comment: are you aware of JQuery Ajax calls?

Comment: Not so much, only some simple operations following tutorials.

Comment: I had Updated my code. If you require complete steps then i'll update above ans as well.

Comment: Do I put this in a HTML source content webpart on the formedit and formnew page? Here is an example of what I have. http://www.base-online.nl/test/spsampel.JPG

Comment: The Artikel column is a lookup list. The Artikel:Prijs per eenheid is associated to that lookup list.

Comment: You need to add an script editor web part on you new/edit forms. Then add the CDN reference of JQuery if not already added into you master page. and below it, within script tag put the following code wrapped in a function and add a line to execute this function when dropdown change event occur.

Comment: I'm not really understanding how this is goint te work. Where do I specify what item I would like to fill? $.ajax({
        url: "https://sharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Pricecatalog')/items(  ??this is based on lookup selection on same form??  )",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json,odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function(productData){
            console.log(productData); // This JSON object will give you price.
        }
    });

Comment: Ok, can you tell me from start what is your requirement. As I can see you are already using Additional Lookup columns, which might not be solving your problem. So please describe requirement to fullest.

Comment: I have 2 lists, Product catalog and Orders. What I would like to have is when I make an order and select an Product (from a lookup field), the associated product price gets filled in a field and saved to a static number in the order list. I also like to use this number to calculate a sub-total in combination with a quantity field.

Comment: So if the price edited on product list it wont make any change to the existing order?

Comment: Correct, When an order is made, the price does not need to be updated.

Comment: Ok then follow the steps in below mentioned answer.

Comment: If you find any difficulties executing above please reply back.